# ListBoxItem not selected when CheckBox is checked

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, listbox, wpf-controls

I have a WPF ListBox which contains a `CheckBox` as follow:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox"
             Grid.Row="1"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Customers}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=ReceiveNewsletter}"
                              Margin="0,3,0,0"
                              IsTabStop="False"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

But I am having an issue about `ListBoxItem` highlighting. When I click the `CheckBox`, the `ListBoxItem` does not get highlighted.

Can anyone give me some idea how to solve the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the checkbox should correspond to the selection you can bind the selection to the same property you bound the checkbox to, do so in the `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` using a `Setter` for `IsSelected`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. your solution works when I select the `CheckBox`. But I still want to Item to be highlighted when I de-select the `CheckBox`

Comment: @Jing: Why in the world would you want that? Isn't that be quite irritating and unexpected behavior?

Comment: yeah, I know my `ListBox` behaviours differently. What I want is my `ListBox` behaviour same as `ListView` but with a `CheckBox` in it.

Comment: How about changing the [`SelectionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selectionmode.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I found the solution for my issue. I add event to ListBox `ButtonBase.Click`. Then add `MyListBox.SelectedItem = ((CheckBox)e.OriginalSource).DataContext;`